# jQuery selecting col-data of dynamically added table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic problem with selecting elements using jQuery. I have dynamically added table rows in a table, each with a dynamically generated ID.

I basically have this code that I was using when the table rows did not have an ID. Now, I have added other features which necessitated assigning table rows with IDs.

This was the code I was using before to toggle certain columns in each row:

```
$("#row .col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();
```

This is how I am assigning IDs to my rows:

```
<tr id="row_'+(currentIndex-1)+'">
```

How can I now use jQuery to select the above row with it's dynamic ID and use it with my code to toggle my columns?

I have tried this but id doesn't work:

```
$("#row_'+(currentIndex-1)+' .col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();
```

Comment: what error are you getting? as the code you mentioned has some issue related to "". `$("#row_" + (currentIndex-1) + " .col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();` try this

Comment: I am getting this error in my console: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #row_'+(currentIndex-1)+' .col[data-col='column1']`

Comment: yes there an error in your syntax ... try this `$("#row_" + (currentIndex-1) + " .col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();`

Comment: That works!! Thank you so much. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is you have added extra single quote. remove it and try this.

`$("#row_" + (currentIndex-1) + " .col[data-col='" + col + "']").toggle();`

Comment: can you please click accept this answer. if it's working fine for you.